# Condition based sequence generation for a Table with composite primary key in JPA Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I have a table with composite primary key.The composite primary is a combination of three columns. The column name are "acc_Id","acc_cycle" and "acc_state".Based on the response data which is coming from another api. We have to insert or update the table.please find the sample data of the table

[image]

In the above table sequence will be generated when the state is "NEW" Or "SAVED" but for other states sequence should not generate.I have searched over the web in that some of the article is addressed by using a child entity for the Id column and other one is using JPA Embedded.Kindly advise how to achieve this any example would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance